# Why are the results of the gamm4 function of the gamm4 package different from the standard error displayed by $mer and $gam?

Tags: r, lme4, gam, mgcv

id:268levels
group:10levels

I used the `gamm4` function of the package `gamm4` to fit the following model.

```
gamm4_1 <- gamm4(y~z1+z2+z3+age+height+time+bmi,random=~(1|id)+(1|group),data=data,family=binomial)
```

In this case, the result is given as a list of `mer` and `gam`, but the standard error of `mer` is different from the standard error of `gam`.

```
summary(gamm4_1$mer)$coefficients
                Estimate  Std. Error     z value      Pr(>|z|)
X(Intercept) -5.59491005 0.001737789 -3219.55651  0.000000e+00
Xz1          -0.40110690 0.001739238  -230.62215  0.000000e+00
Xz2          -0.75774666 0.001737744  -436.05193  0.000000e+00
Xz3          -0.16008244 0.001737414   -92.13836  0.000000e+00
Xage         -0.05760610 0.001636062   -35.21022 1.394896e-271
Xheight       0.06065821 0.001120702    54.12520  0.000000e+00
Xtime         0.08710019 0.001737386    50.13290  0.000000e+00
Xbmi          0.04417464 0.001732751    25.49393 2.301696e-143
```

```
summary(gamm4_1$gam)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + age + height + time + bmi

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -5.59491    2.69546  -2.076  0.03792 *  
z1          -0.40111    0.17302  -2.318  0.02044 *  
z2          -0.75775    0.37128  -2.041  0.04126 *  
z3          -0.16008    0.34723  -0.461  0.64478    
age         -0.05761    0.01850  -3.115  0.00184 ** 
height       0.06066    0.01329   4.563 5.03e-06 ***
time         0.08710    0.06609   1.318  0.18750    
bmi          0.04417    0.03350   1.319  0.18733    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Why are the coefficients the same, but the standard error values are completely different?

Comment: Going on the information above, I'd guess that you are in or close to a separation problem wherein your covariate combinations can perfectly (or very closely) split the response into 1s and 0s. I'm guessing because you haven't even told us what `y` is. Why are you even fitting this via `gamm4()`? There are no smooths here; would fitting in `glmer()` not just be easier? If you can afford the compute time, refitting with `gam(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + age + height + time + bmi + s(id, bs = "re") + s(group, bs = "re"), data = data, family = binomial, method = "REML"), might show where the problem lies

Comment: Because of the large number of random effects, I thought it would be better to use gamm or gamm4. After refitting with ```gam(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + age + height + time + bmi + s(id, bs = "re") + s(group, bs = "re")```, The output is almost identical to the result of ```summary(gamm4_1$gam)```. After all, do you know why the standard errors are so different for $mer and $gam? @GavinSimpson

Comment: This is pretty deep.  If you're digging around inside a `gamm4` object you really need to know what's going on ...

Comment: That's difficult for me to do, so I think I'll forget about ```gamm4``` and use a different function this time! @BenBolker

Comment: I share @GavinSImpson's curiosity about why you're using `gamm4` for a model where `lme4` would do (it's better documented and various downstream tasks are much better supported) (do you intend to add smooth terms to the model, but you haven't shown them in your examples?). FWIW `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` is a little old fashioned relative to SO, but there's a good concentration of people with opinions and/or knowledge about mixed models there ...

Comment: Thanks. I use ```gamm4``` to compare with models with bmi and age as smooth terms. Also, since I am using a model with a smooth term added in the model for another outcome variable, I wanted to match the function used. @BenBolker

Comment: I started to dig into this a little bit. My simple examples aren't diverging as much as yours are. Any chance of a [mcve] ... ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried many things, but I only got the result that the standard error of $mer and $gam are the same. Maybe there is a problem with the data. @BenBolker